# Hibernate: ManyToMany unidirectional only returning one record

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have this problem and I'd appreciate any help...

I have a User entity. A user has a Role (a many to one relationship). And a role has a list of permissions (the many to many relationshp I'm having trouble with).

In my code, I am selecting a single user out of the database, by username.

When I retrieve the user, the user's role is there inside of it. But inside the role, there should be a list of permissions. There should be 4 permissions, but every time, I am only getting one element back in the set.

I have queried the database correctly, and there are indeed 4 permissions attached to that role, so the problem isnt there.

UserEntity:

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotEmpty
  private String username;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  private RoleEntity role;
}
```

RoleEntity:

```
@Table(name = "roles")
public class RoleEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotEmpty
  private String name;

  private String description;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "roles_permissions", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
  private Set<PermissionEntity> permissions = new HashSet<>();

}
```

And here is my repository. I'm calling this method from a service, and am just getting back what I described above.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, String> {

  Optional<UserEntity> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

In my database, I have a table called 'roles_permissions' with the fields role_id and permission_id. There are four records in here. role_id is '1' for all of them, and its linked to permissions 1,2,3,4.

In the users table, there is a field for role_id. And the user that I'm selecting has this field populated with 1.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, nevermind. I've been working on this for a while, and I figured it out as soon as I posted this!

In the @JoinTable annotation, I had "role_id" and "permission_id" the wrong way around!